# c# No overload for method takes 0 arguments (Trying to call method from another method)

Tags: c#

This is my method which i'm trying to call,

```
private Label UserIdLabelAssignText(int counter, string userId)
{
    Label userIdLabel = this.Controls.Find("userIdLabel" + counter.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
    if (userIdLabel == null) userIdLabel = this.Controls.Find(userId + "UserIdLabel", true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
    if (userIdLabel != null)
    {
        userIdLabel.Text = (userId);
        userIdLabel.Name = userId + "UserIdLabel";
        userIdLabel.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    return userIdLabel;
}
```

And this is where I'm calling from.

```
private void Refresh_App_TimerNH_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    i = i + 1;
    if (i == 16)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    UserIdLabelAssignText();
}
```

I'm new to c#.

Comment: You need to read more about OOP, your question is basic about calling methods. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserIdLabelAssignText` is defined with 2 arguments
you call `UserIdLabelAssignText()` thus giving 0 args which is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Your method is waiting for two parameters

```
private void Refresh_App_TimerNH_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    i = i + 1;
    if (i == 16)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    else
    {

    }

    UserIdLabelAssignText(i,"test"); //integer parameter and string parameter needed

}
```